# Have Wordpress Read a Shortcode String and Parse a Variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

I have a countdown timer on my Wordpress site. For reference I used [this tutorial](https://mindgrader.com/tutorials/1-how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer). I call/include the .js from a child theme via the footer of my site.

Currently the tutorial has me inserting the countdown timer via `<span id="countdown"></span>`.

I would like to insert the countdown timer instead, with a shortcode, that contains a variable to be parsed into the .js to set the target date.

Here is the relevant line of code from the js file, with the static/hard coded date. This is where I want to forward my variable to.

`var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();`

This way I can use a single .js include to create multiple countdown timers.

E.g. Shortcode: `[Countdown Timer target="Aug 15, 2019"]`

How do I get Wordpress to recognise the shortcode, load the span id and parse the variable to set the target date/time?

Note: I don't mind installing a plugin if there is complexity having the shortcode work. My main requirement is to be able to parse a variable, so if it can be done some other way I'd be happy to look into that.

Comment: Are you looking to have multiple timers on the same page?

Comment: Quite likely, so I suppose I had better account for that. Will that mean a second variable?

Comment: I just whipped up a solution that works for a single timer per page.  Unfortunately I'm having issues getting multiple timers per page to work.

Comment: OK great. I'll give it a try.

Comment: See my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will allow for a single timer per page.  I know you said you may possibly need more than one, but if not, this will work.

Include this JS somewhere in your site.  Notice I have have it inside of  `.ready`, please make sure it stays that way.  I also deleted a single line from your example, which will be set with the shortcode.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

        var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

        setInterval(function () {

            var current_date = new Date().getTime();
            var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

            days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

            hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

            minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
            seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

            countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
            + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

        }, 1000);
    });     
</script>
```

Then include this PHP in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function aw_countdown_timer ($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'target_date' => '',
    ), $atts, 'aw_countdownTimer' ));
    echo '<script>var target_date = new Date("' . $target_date . '").getTime();</script>';
    echo '<span id="countdown"></span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'aw_countdownTimer', 'aw_countdown_timer' );
```

Then you can use this shortcode `[aw_countdownTimer target_date="Feb 14, 2014"]` in any page.  Just change the `Feb 14, 2014` to your desired date, but make sure to use that exact format.

Comment: Not quite working for me yet. I added functions.php to my child theme and included your code (within PHP tags). When I load the page and view source I see `<div class="entry-summary">
      <script>var target_date = new Date("Feb 14, 2014").getTime();</script><span id="countdown"></span> <br/>
  </div>`. Am I missing something? Also why do we define two shortcode types?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "two shortcode types".  There is only one shortcode there.  If you're referring to `add_shortcode( 'aw_countdownTimer', 'aw_countdown_timer' );` then `aw_countdownTimer` is the name of the shortcode and `aw_countdown_timer` is the function that the shortcode executes.

Comment: Did you do exactly what my answer said to do with the JS?  That is a must for this to work.

Comment: Also, I just removed a `<br/>` from the PHP, it was only there for my testing and I initially forgot to remove it.

Comment: Yes I simply replaced my .js with yours. It's still being included via the footer on my site. Maybe it's happening in the wrong order... should it be in the header? (Regarding my other question... I figured that out thanks)

Comment: Whoops it's working now. I had to remove the .js tags:) Thanks again. Let me know if you think of a way for multiple timers. I'll leave the question unanswered for a day or two to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: Sounds good, if I have some time to play with it some more I'll see what I can do with multiple timers.